# What does this step do in Texture Paint?

Tags: texturing

I was watching a tutorial about texture paint and the teacher said:

> Go to “**Active Tool and WorkSpace Settings**” tab > **Texture Slots** section.
>    Change the Mode to Single Image. Don’t create a new image. Just pick the name of the image that you’ve just created.

The image that I selected appeared on the object and he said that this connects the image to the object. But I still don't understand what this does or what he means by "connects". Of course, it's not connected to the object as a material. Is this step just to shows us what part of the image are we painting on? Just for a demonstration purpose?

Comment: Simple objects or low realism 3D objects may only require a single texture. Do you understand that some 3D objects with complex or high realism appearance may require many textures?  Suppose you present a dull object such as a old ball and you want a optional shiny wet hand print to appear and disappear. This might easily be done with 2 textures.  Thus for the Blender User, Blender gives a mechanism to command which texture the [texture paint] mechanism is to use now in the UI.  Dull and Shiny are just two examples.  These multiple textures are evident in the node system which you can view.

Comment: The connection may be evident in the texture nodes for materials because it is the permanent record saved in the Blender file.  Perhaps this is the display of information that may be helpful. Part of that record is called ... slots.